# First order optimality conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, frechet-derivative

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces, and $f(x,y)$ be a nonlinear maps that maps $X\times Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The mapping $f$ is Frechet differentiable with respect to each variable $x$ and $y$. In order to obtain the first-order necessary optimality conditions, one needs to set $$f'_x=f'_y=0.$$
Do we need to check if the second order derivative $f'_{x,y}$ exists?

Comment: Are you looking for a maximum? Generally, the second derivative (or the Hessian in n-d) should also have a sufficient condition depending on if you are looking for maxima or minima.

Comment: Here we are only discussing about first-order necessary conditions.

Comment: Then I don't think you should have any need to check for any properties of the second order derivatives